# XSLT from a 'Template XML'

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, export

So having tried to work out how to export from MS Access so the resulting XML had the same Element Name and nodes as one that has come from another source.. i have not succeeded..

So am looking at exporting from MS Access to XML and then using an XSLT to transfrom the data in the file so that it can be read.

if anyone could help me because i have tried and failed at coding an XSLT all day to get what i need??

Basically, i need an XSLT created that would transform all XML exports to have the same Element names, and nodes as in my 'Template XML'

My Template XML is as follows...

```
<DatabaseData>
<Customers>
 <Idx>0</Idx>
 <FirstName/>
 <LastName>Undefined</LastName>
 <IconIdx>0</IconIdx>
 <PhoneNumber/>
 <Email/>
 <Street/>
 <City/>
 <State/>
 <ZipCode/>
 <Available>1</Available>
 <SPIndex>0</SPIndex>
 </Customers>
 </DatabaseData>
```

//edit// apologies..

I have tried to create my own XSLT but i feel it is lacking..

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:element name="DatabaseData">
    <xsl:element name="Customers">
        <Idx><xsl:value-of select="Idx" /></Idx>
        <FirstName><xsl:value-of select="FirstName" /></FirstName>
        <LastName><xsl:value-of select="LastName" /></LastName>
        <IconIdx><xsl:value-of select="IconIdx" /></IconIdx>
        <PhoneNumber><xsl:value-of select="PhoneNumber" /></PhoneNumber>
        <Email><xsl:value-of select="Email" /></Email>
        <Street><xsl:value-of select="Street" /></Street>
        <City><xsl:value-of select="City" /></City>
        <State><xsl:value-of select="State" /></State>
        <ZipCode><xsl:value-of select="ZipCode" /></ZipCode>
        <Available><xsl:value-of select="Available" /></Available>
        <SPIndex><xsl:value-of select="SPIndex" /></SPIndex>
    </Customers>
</DatabaseData>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

The outputted info from Access to XML is as follows:

```
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2014-07-    29T14:28:34">
<Customers>
 <Idx>1</Idx>
 <FirstName>David</FirstName>
 <LastName>James</LastName>
 <IconIdx>0</IconIdx>
 <PhoneNumber>00000 000000</PhoneNumber>
 <Email>david@email.com</Email>
 <Street/>
 <City>London</City>
 <State>London</State>
 <ZipCode>AB3 CD4</ZipCode>
 <Available>0</Available>
 <SPIndex>0</SPIndex>
 </Customers>
</dataroot>
```

So i need to..

a. Change 'dataroot' to 'DatabaseData'
b. Remove the 'Generated' node whilst also removing the 'xlmns:od' that Access puts in place after the export..

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your stylesheet could be compacted to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <DatabaseData>
        <xsl:copy-of select="dataroot/Customers"/>
    </DatabaseData>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

--

> ... whilst also removing the 'xlmns:od' that Access puts in place
>   after the export..

I don't see that part in your input.

---

### Edit:

To remove the (harmless) namespace declaration, you will need to do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <DatabaseData>
        <xsl:for-each select="dataroot/Customers">
            <Customers>
                <Idx><xsl:value-of select="Idx"/></Idx>
                <FirstName><xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/></FirstName>
                <LastName><xsl:value-of select="LastName"/></LastName>
                <IconIdx><xsl:value-of select="IconIdx"/></IconIdx>
                <PhoneNumber><xsl:value-of select="PhoneNumber"/></PhoneNumber>
                <Email><xsl:value-of select="Email"/></Email>
                <Street><xsl:value-of select="Street"/></Street>
                <City><xsl:value-of select="City"/></City>
                <State><xsl:value-of select="State"/></State>
                <ZipCode><xsl:value-of select="ZipCode"/></ZipCode>
                <Available><xsl:value-of select="Available"/></Available>
                <SPIndex><xsl:value-of select="SPIndex"/></SPIndex>
            </Customers>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </DatabaseData>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or, if you prefer a more generic solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <DatabaseData>
        <Customers>
            <xsl:for-each select="dataroot/Customers/*">
                <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Customers>
    </DatabaseData>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

IOW, you cannot use `copy` or `copy-of`, otherwise the processor will preserve the namespace declaration in case it's needed further downstream.

Comment: I have edited the outputted xml info to include where the xmlns is included in the xml

Comment: @Davidskibob It's a harmless declaration and you shouldn't mind it. Removing it is possible only if you laboriously list out all output elements explicitly, together with the input elements they need to take their value from - the way you have started to do.

Comment: I appreciate your help! And regarding the xmlns.. For the machine hat I am using to read the file it cannot have the xmlns otherwise it will not read the xml properly!

Comment: it's annoying and would rather it did, but whoever wrote the program for the Machine was obviously feeling nasty! Haha

Comment: @Davidskibob Incompetent would be my guess... See the edit to my post.

Comment: thank you so uch for this!! this does exactly what i want it to do, so i was sort of along the lines, just been looking through to see how it was different